# How to use parted in script mode to create 3 partitions

Tags: partition, system-installation, hard-disk, chroot, gparted

Trying to create an installation script for a from-base linux distribution.

- The first partition I would like to create is a 1G /boot
- The second should be a variable sized swap partition (current RAM*2)
- The third will be 100% or 50% of the remaining free space (depending on user choice)

I know `parted -s` allows you to specify the START sector and END sector, but documentation has been scarce and I have not been able to determine how to have that start sector be "first available free space" and the end sector "+16G" or so.

Any help with this, or a solution using a similar tool, would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Most systems are now UEFI, so you need an ESP - efi system partition FAT32  which should not be confused with a /boot Linux format partition. And /boot not normally required, but some server, LVM or LVM with encryption may need a /boot. And most should use gpt partitioning over  the very old MBR partitioning. If not using ESP, then you need a bios_grub partition for BIOS boot on gpt partitioned drives.

Comment: My use case is MBR. The partition layout I have described is correct.

Comment: While you can use  MBR and with Linux boot in either BIOS or UEFI mode, often better to use gpt even if booting BIOS mode. GPT Advantages (older 2010 but still valid)  see post#2 by srs5694:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1457901 & 
https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Partitioning#Choosing_between_GPT_and_MBR

Comment: Thats great. But my target hardware doesn't support UEFI and that's why I'm asking about an MBR style partition layout.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write installation script, because there is kickstart file for that purpose.

For example, on redhat site there is kickstart generator:

https://access.redhat.com/labs/kickstartconfig/

Example kickstart file configuration:

```
# Partition clearing information
clearpart --none --initlabel
# Disk partitioning information
part pv.166 --fstype="lvmpv" --ondisk=sda --size=50175
part /boot --fstype="xfs" --ondisk=sda --size=1024
volgroup ol --pesize=4096 pv.166
logvol /  --fstype="xfs" --grow --maxsize=51200 --size=1024 --name=root --vgname=ol
logvol swap  --fstype="swap" --size=4096 --name=swap --vgname=ol
```

Comment: This is not a general solution, this is applicable only for Red Hat/Fedora derivatives. I could not use this in a from-base Alpine or Arch install.